# Root Test for Convergence or Divergence (ln problem)

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I'm stuck at this problem. How would I approach this (I have to use the root test for this one)? The ln and e and my power is throwing me off.

[image]

This is how far I have gotten.

Comment: How does this sequence tend towards zero?  The root test is unnecessary here (unless you have written it incorrectly).  Also you are misusing the equals sign here.  The sum of the series isn't equal to the root test.

Comment: $\lim\root n\of\cdots$ **isn't** the sum of the series!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just use the test for divergence. Take the limit

$$ \displaystyle\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left [ \ln \left (e^9 + \frac{1}{n} \right) \right ]^{n+8}$$. That clearly does not go to zero. Hence the series is divergence.

(You can't use L'Hopital's here because it is not an indeterminate form.)

EDIT: I didn't notice that the solution has to be by root test.

---

By ROOT TEST:

$$ \displaystyle\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left [ \ln \left (e^9 + \frac{1}{n} \right) \right ]^{\dfrac{n+8}{n}}$$

So the exponent should read: $1+ \dfrac{8}{n}$. So as $n \to \infty$, the result is clearly greater than 1. Hence, the series is divergence.